# how to keep SubjectAltName as as commonName in openssl conf file

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

I am working on building a Certificate Authority on my centos server. I have completed the setup following OpenSSL Cookbook (great stuff) from `https://www.feistyduck.com/books/openssl-cookbook/` The concepts explained in the book and procedure is very simple and worked like charm. However, I feel it was a bit outdated and chrome browser changed the behavior to require Subject Alternative Name otherwise it gives browser warning even though the certificate is perfectly valid.

After reading the documentation at `https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/x509v3_config.html#Subject-Alternative-Name` I could understand that I need to include that in my conf file of root CA and sub-ca (intermdiate Certificate Authority).

Now what I want to do is to use the commonName as SAN. That means instead of hardcoding SAN, I want to take whatever the value I get from CSR for CommonName and use that as SAN. 
What should I put in conf file to achieve this? 
I tried to put 
subjectAltName          = $commonName
and it is telling me that it is not a valid way of defining SAN.

Here is my actual conf file

```
https://pastebin.com/UtCDU4BE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer might help https://security.stackexchange.com/a/91556. As @Jon already mentioned. It's only possible with the help of a template.
Make sure you validated the input. Otherwise someone can inject a new line into the DNS name.
An other solution to the problem could be to use https://github.com/cloudflare/cfssl or https://github.com/google/easypki instead.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the OpenSSL conf files aren't at all sophisticated, and it isn't possible to refer to previously declared names.

I think the usual approach is to write a short script which can fill in a template conf file. It's certainly what I've done in the past.